# What is an effective way to copy Athena databases?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have an Athena db that I would like to duplicate (with a different name of course). Right now, I don't have an effective way to do this. My approach right now is just to execute CTAS queries per table but this obviously doesn't work for databases with 100s of tables. I've also looked into using crawlers but unfortunately, I do not always have a reliable S3 export for this.

Is there a way for me to duplicate Athena databases? Perhaps a shell script?

Comment: Do you just want to copy the database metadase, like table defintions or the underlying S3 data as well?

Comment: An Athena database is just a table definition, which points to the data in S3. Are you wanting to create another table definition that points to the same data, or to different data? Or are you trying to replicate the data in S3 in another location? Please Edit your question to add more details of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein think he wants to create another table definition that points to a different s3 data but same structure. data structure is same but the actual data is different. Like QA vs Production vs Dev.

Comment: @VNarasimhaM Oh, that makes sense -- I think you're right! They could probably use the AWS Glue [`get_table()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_table) command to retrieve details about a table and then call [`create_table()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_table) to create a matching table in another database.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python script that basically reads all the tables in the database and does a CTAS which I haven't tested:

```
import boto3

source_name = 'source'
target_name = 'target'

athena_client = boto3.client('athena')

# Get the source database
get_database_response = athena_client.get_database(
    CatalogName='AwsDataCatalog',
    DatabaseName=source_name
)
source_database = get_database_response['Database']

# Create the target database with the same input, might need to remove some properties from the input.
create_database_response = athena_client.create_database(
    CatalogName='AwsDataCatalog',
    DatabaseInput=source_database,
    DatabaseName=target_name
)

list_tables_response = athena_client.list_table_metadata(
    CatalogName='AwsDataCatalog',
    DatabaseName=source_name
)
tables = list_tables_response['TableMetadataList']

# Copy each table
for table in tables:
    table_name = table['Name']
    create_table_sql = f"CREATE TABLE {target_name}.{table_name} AS SELECT * FROM {source_name}.{table_name}"
    athena_client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=create_table_sql,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': target_name
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': 's3://output-bucket/',
        }
    )
```